# Convert horizontal range to array and print

Tags: excel, vba

I can't print a horizontal range. This is surprising, because my code works perfectly for a vertical range. What didn’t I understand?

```
Sub hello()

    Dim i As Long

    Dim enumTitles As Variant

    Dim listTitles() As Variant

    ' enumTitles = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hello").Range("A1:A3")
    ' Works.

    enumTitles = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hello").Range("A1:C1")
    ' Doesn't work.

    listTitles = enumTitles

    For i = LBound(listTitles, 1) To UBound(listTitles, 1)

       Debug.Print (listTitles(i, 1))

       'Only one result is displayed. Not three.

    Next i

End Sub
```

The goal is not to print obviously. It is to reuse its values.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: the `1` in `listTitles(i, 1)` is the first column. If you don't increment the column, then you'll only get one result.

Comment: One is 3 x 1, the other 1 x 3 ...

Comment: @BigBen Thanks. Something like this? (display only two results...)
`
For i = 1 To 3
 For k = LBound(listTitles, i) To UBound(listTitles, i)
    Debug.Print (listTitles(i))
 Next k
Next i
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel range() function will return 2D array to the *enumTitles*.

So, when you are running it for rows the code print all values of 1st row.
But columns is the second dimension of the 2D array, that's why you are receiving only 1st value (all values of 1st row again).

For Columns Loop you have to use 2nd dimension as below:

```
' Use len of 2nd dimension
For i = LBound(listTitles, 2) To UBound(listTitles, 2)
  ' Loop by columnt ID
  Debug.Print (listTitles(1, i))
Next i
```

Comment: Your suggestion is very interesting. It is close to the expected result. Your explanation is simple and clear. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate the elements of the array:

```
Sub dural()
    enumTitles = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hello").Range("A1:C1")
    For Each a In enumTitles
        msg = msg & a & " "
    Next a
    Debug.Print (msg)
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To get a **specific item** in the array we must either know its position or use a loop to find it.  Say we know that *beta* is the 2<sup>nd</sup> element in a horizontal array.  We would:

```
Debug.Print (enumTitles(1, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfecly. But how can I deal directly 'beta" for instance ?

Comment: @384400  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Extremely simple and obvious. :)